# Starting Python script via py.exe is exponentially slower than via python.exe - How comes, and can I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.8, windows-11

I'm on Windows 11. I recently got into Python and wrote a little helper script with a GUI interface to help manage some of my projects. When I run this Python script by passing it directly to the Python 3.8 executable (python.exe) via the command line, it has a start-up time of only around 2 seconds, which I find acceptable.

However, when I just double-click the file, Windows will pass it to py.exe instead and the start-up time will be around 34 to 37 seconds, which I think is abyssmal. Especially when using a .pyw file instead, which doesn't display a command line window, so you don't even really see that any work is being done in the background.

From what I understand, py.exe is just the Python launcher that's included in Windows. Its purpose is to manage multiple Python installations. Because it's so slow, I originally assumed it did this by analyzing Python scripts to determine which Python version was best suitable for them. However, according to [Microsoft's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/faqs#what-is-py-exe-), that's not the case and it instead just picks the highest installed version by default.

My next guess was that maybe searching for Python installations was in and of itself a slow task. I know that Windows' file system can be ridiculously slow for certain purposes and assumed it could be related to that. However, running `py.exe -0` on the command line takes just a fraction of a second to complete and lists me all six Python versions that are installed on my system. So once again, that doesn't seem to be the cause. Windows seems to already know which Python versions are installed, so it doesn't seem like searching for them should take a lot of time. Even if I just start a Python interpreter directly via py.exe and don't pass in a script path, like `py.exe -3.8`, I still get the ridiculous start-up time. So it definitely isn't related to my script, either.

So then all of that begs the question: Why exactly is py.exe so ridiculously slow? Is that a Windows 11-only issue? Is it caused by having so many Python installations? Is the launcher itself just really bad? And is there anything I can do about this? I know I could probably just create a .bat file that does `pythonw.exe my_script.pyw`, but this feels kinda silly, and it wouldn't necessarily pick the most appropriate Python version for every user. Are there any other alternatives? Preferably ones that work out of the box and don't require installing additional dependencies?

Comment: Try disabling antivirus

Comment: I don't actually use any anti-virus besides what's included with Windows. I tried disabling Windows real-time protection, but it had no noticable impact on start-up time whatsoever.